# Calculation with only positive numbers returns negative number when using Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

Calculation with only positive numbers returns negative number.

The source code is below.

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp(code = "
  #include <Rcpp.h>
  //[[Rcpp::export]]
  double test4(int n, int m, int i) {
    double out = (double)(n * i) / (double)(m + 1); 
    return out;
  }
")
test4(10000,1000000, as.integer(3*10^5))
```

This phenomenon happens when using large values as arguments.

I want correct return value.

How Should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are taking the product `n * i` using integers. If these are large, you get an integer overflow, since the maximum number representable by an 32 bit signed int is 2147483647. And for signed integers, overflow results in negative numbers. An easy fix is to do the cast before the multiplication:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp(code = "
  #include <Rcpp.h>
  //[[Rcpp::export]]
  double test4(int n, int m, int i) {
    double out = (double)n * i / (double)(m + 1); 
    return out;
  }
")
test4(10000,1000000, as.integer(3*10^5))
```

Result:

```
2999.997
```

BTW, I am not changing the C-style casts here, but generally C++-style casts are preferred IMHO.